# ng-table data will be shown in one line in one array instead of multiple lines

Tags: arrays, angularjs, ngtable

Each click on my google Map adds new data to my array.
I have this array:
`tableDATA = [{range:[],distances:[]}];`

This are the push commands in the click function:
"total" and "round" are calculated integers
`tableDATA[0].distances.push(total+' km');`
`tableDATA[0].range.push(round+' km');`

This is my ng-table params code in javascript

```
    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams(
    {
        page: 1,            // show first page
        count: 15,          // count per page
        sorting: {
            distances: 'asc'      // initial sorting
        }
    },
    {
        total: tableDATA[0].distances.length, // length of data
        getData: function($defer, params) {
            // use build-in angular filter
            var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                $filter('orderBy')(tableDATA, params.orderBy()) : tableDATA;
            $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
        }
    }
);
```

And this is my ng-table code in html

```
<button ng-click="tableParams.sorting({})" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Clear sorting</button>
        <p><strong>Sorting:</strong> {{tableParams.sorting()|json}}</p>
        <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
            <tr ng-repeat="point in $data">
                <td data-title="'real'" sortable="'real'">{{point.distances}}</td>
                <td data-title="'Kombi'" sortable="'Kombi'">{{point.range}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

The entries in the array won't be shown in multiple lines (one entry per line) but in one line with all array entries:

```
                           real                                   Kombi
line 1:       ["50.32 km","50.89 km", etc.]           ["44.32 km","48.65 km", etc.]
line 2: won't be created
line 3: won't be created
```

**What's wrong? Pls help**

Answer (score 0):

try using an angular foreach see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

Comment: I'm being Stupid. Because the repeater is in a <TD> of course it will go across. you can use a couple of <div> tags instead and not do it in a table or ensure ALL the repeaters are on <tr>

Comment: If i put all repeaters on <tr> no data will be shown.
The table needs the following structure: <tr> for a row and then <td> for the data.

Comment: Why dont you just drop the table all together and use div's instead. This should resolve your issue. You could set the outer div's width to be 100% and the 2 inner div's to be say 48% this will give you 2 columns and it should act like your table in terms look

Answer (score 0):

I don't come to the right solution with forEach because I have an array behind the keys and no static values.. ?!

```
var tableDATA_arr = []; 
tableDATA = {range:[],distances:[]}; 

tableDATA.distances.push(total+' km'); 
tableDATA.range.push(round+' km'); 

angular.forEach(tableDATA, function(value, key) {
   this.push(key + ': ' + value);
}, tableDATA_arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr ng-repeat="point in $data">
<td><tr ng-repeat="distance in point.distances">
                <td data-title="'real'" sortable="'real'">{{distance}}</td>
</tr></td>
```

then do the same for the other column

Comment: thanks for your answer but the problem still exists... see my answer

Answer (score 0):

This is my code now. The data is retrievable(!), but the data still will be written in one line -.- i hate it :D

```
<tr ng-repeat="point in $data">
    <td ng-repeat="dist in point.distances track by $index" data-title="'real'" sortable="'real'">
        {{dist}}
    </td>
    <td ng-repeat="range in point.range track by $index" data-title="'Kombi'" sortable="'Kombi'">
        {{range}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake.
First the table data array had a structure like this: `tableDATA = [{range:[],distances:[]}];`
There was only one object at all times and only the arrays in this one object got filled.
I changed the table data array to: `tableDATA = [];` and per each click I fill the array with a new object like this: `tableDATA.push({range:round+' km',distances:total+' km'});`
**Now it works fine :)**